# iOS best way to connect and maintain connection to a BLE peripheral

Tags: ios, singleton, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im trying to understand which is the best way to maintain the connection across view controllers.

Currently I have a NSObject class which implements CBCentralManagerDelegate and CBPeripheralDelegate methods.

I have another class, BLEManager that uses a singleton to create an instance of the CBCentralManager class and an NSStream class that communicates with the peripheral.

I am running into errors when scanning for and connecting to peripherals. When finding wrong devices with the same service UUIDs, the app tries to connect and alerts the user. However when I try to discover and connect again, it just tries to reconnect with the same device.

Could this be due to the way i've set up my singleton?

Also would it be better to make my NSObject class a singleton instead rather than having the BLEManager singleton?

Comment: How do you know which device you want to connect to?  Once you have its identifier there is no need to scan, you can just connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see some code?? Maybe with code we can help you better. But I think is not a Singleton problem, but a NSObject problem. Check that you have only one instance of that object, because if the object implements the BLE delegate, and you have many instances of it, your app will enter the delegate methods as many times as instances you have.

Could it be the problem?